# How to remove ALL duplicate values from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I want to check only the value [id] for duplicates, and remove all keys where this "field" [id] is a duplicate.

Example: If I have numbers 1,2,1. I want the result to be 2, not 1,2. And criteria for duplicates is determined only by checking [id], not any other "field".

**Original array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [id] => 123
            [color] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Paul
            [id] => 958
            [color] => red
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jennifer
            [id] => 123
            [color] => yellow
        )
)
```

**The result I want:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Paul
            [id] => 958
            [color] => red
        )

)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot just for loop through this? If so explain, but otherwise, we are not the code factory you've been looking for.

Comment: You can use bubble sort like algorithm to remove duplicates. So if there is a match remove both elements without the sorting part.

Comment: Don't put code in comments please!

Comment: @JonTaylor Yeah, that's why I deleted my comment

Comment: @Boriana no he was pretty clear what it was he wanted.  What he wrote is correct.

Comment: Make an array containing the count of repetitions of each ID. Then go through the original array again, removing items if the ID's count > 1.

Comment: @infinity what if there are an odd number of repeating elements?

Comment: @Eagle that's good point, my idea won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fairly easy to accomplish with a couple of simple loops:

```
set_time_limit(0); // Disable time limit to allow enough time to process a large dataset

// $items contains your data

$id_counts = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (array_key_exists($item['id'], $id_counts)) {
        $id_counts[$item['id']]++;
    } else {
        $id_counts[$item['id']] = 1;
    }
}

for ($i = count($items); $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if ($id_counts[$items[$i]['id']] > 1) {
        array_splice($items, $i, 1);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Paul
            [id] => 958
            [color] => red
        )
)
```

While there are neater ways to do it, one advantage of this method is you're only creating new arrays for the list of ids and duplicate ids and the `array_splice` is removing the duplicates from the original array, so memory usage is kept to a minimum.

Edit: Fixed a bug that meant it sometimes left one behind

Comment: thank you so much, it worked! I've been trying to do this for 12 hours already...

Comment: FYI - just re-read the code and realised the nested loop in the second step was unnecessary; edited it to be faster and simpler.

Comment: it works great for "small" amount of arrays, however when I tried to process 40,000 my browser produced 500 internal server error after 2 minutes. I guess it is some sort of a timeout. Is there any way to make this more efficient? I would need to probably process about 1 million arrays.

Comment: You can disable the timeout with `set_time_limit`, which will allow the script to run for as long as it needs to. I've also updated the code to make it faster and consume even less memory, see my most recent edit. Hopefully this will help - check your logs if you're still getting an error, as you may need to increase the script's memory limit too (see `memory_limit`)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with everyone above, you should give us more information about what you've tried, but I like to code golf, so here's a completely unreadble solution:

```
$new_array = array_filter($array, function($item) use (&$array){
    return count(array_filter($array, function($node) use (&$item){
        return $node['id'] == $item['id'];
    })) < 2;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function PickUniques(array $items){
    // Quick way out
    if(empty($items)) return array();
    $counters = array();
    // Count occurences
    foreach($items as $item){
        $item['id'] = intval($item['id']);
        if(!isset($counters[$item['id']])){
            $counters[$item['id']] = 0;
        }
        $counters[$item['id']]++;
    }
    // Pop multiples occurence ones
    foreach($counters as $id => $occurences){
        if($occurences > 1){
            unset($counters[$id]);
        }
    }
    // Keep only those that occur once (in $counters)
    $valids = array();
    foreach($items as $item){
        if(!isset($items[$item['id']])) continue;
        $valids[$item['id']] = $item;
    }
    return $valids;
}
```

Try this one :)

Comment: He doesn't want ANY match of duplicates.

Comment: I must be drunk. Fixing it in a moment :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic approach to the answer and I am sure there are much better answers however I would probably start by doing it the way I would on paper.

I look at the first index, check its value.  Then I go through every other index making note of their index if the value is the same as my originally noted value.  Once I have gone through the list if I have more than one index with that particular value I remove them all (starting with the highest index, so as to not affect indexes of the others while deleting).

Do this for all other indexes till you reach the end of the list.

It is long winded but will make sure it removes all values which have duplicates. and leaves only those which originally had no duplicates.